# Java function algorithm to add minutes to time

Tags: java, algorithm, time, modulo, timeofday

I'm writing a function that adds minutes to a time string - without using any libraries for Time. The function takes two arguments -

1. The first, a "time" ([H]H:MM AM|PM) String, in the format of something like `12:00 AM` or `3:30 PM` (12-hour clock, *no (24-hourclock) military time input*)
2. The *second*, an integer argument (positive or negative) as *minutes*, i.e. `200`

Everything is *fine-and-dandy* until I came across adding *negative* minutes. For example, I can get the correct answer when having the first argument input as `02:00 AM`, and the second argument input as `-180`, which should yield the **answer** of **11:00 PM**.

*My algorithm* I use is to take my input String "time"/first argument, i.e. `02:00 AM`, and convert/map that to **military time (24-hour clock)** for all my calculations (so I don't have to keep track of AM or PM), then I convert the entire thing to **minutes**, then I convert to **hours** and take % (modulo) with 24 (since 1 day is 24 hours) to get **HOURS** portion answer, and I use the previously computed **minutes** and % (modulo) with 60 to get the **MINUTES** portion of the answer.

In this example I gave above (02:00 AM) and (-180), would result in:

1. 02:00AM == 120 minutes
2. Add 120 minutes + (-180) minutes = -60 minutes
3. Convert minutes (i.e. 60) to hours = -1 hr
4. Use `Math.floorMod(-1,24)` = 23, to get the Hours portion of the answer. Using just `%` gives me the wrong answer of `1`...
5. Use -60 % 60 = 0, to get the **MINUTES** portion of the answer. Regular % operators works fine here
6. Concatenate hours + minutes + AM/PM to return a String like `11:00 PM`

I have been using the `Math.floorMod(x,y)`, since the regular modulo `%` operator was not working for me, when subtracting and ending up with negative numbers that I needed to take the modulo of. I was now trying different inputs like `9:13 AM` with `-720` (half day) and `-1440` (full day) of minutes and now I was getting some wrong answers.

It seems like when **adding** the minutes to a time using this modulus algorithm I *always* get the correct answer. Do I have to do something different now that I am essentially *subtracting* minutes and possibly ending up with negative numbers that I take modulo with 24?

Please let me know.

Comment: Why are you not using any library? If it’s for an exercise, it’s a good exercise, but for production code one should use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And why are you keeping your time of day in a string? A representation involving numbers would seem more natural and practical to me. Like count of minutes since 00:00, from 0 through 1439, just to give one thinkable example..

Comment: It would be easier to give a precise answer if we could see and maybe even try running your code.

Comment: @OleV.V. I can post the code, but its a lot of generic/obvious stuff like when I map to 24-hour clock (military time) , its just a gigantic-switch statement and its a lot of code/ugly and would fill up the page fast. I thought pseudo-code would be fine, since the problem is actually quite simple, despite how much I wrote. I see you posted a solution below, I will verify it in a minute here after breakfast :D thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that you may still get negative minutes. You may try adding for example -135 minutes rather than -180 and see what happens.

I think you will be better off reversing the operations:

1. First use `Math.floorMod(-60, 24 * 60)` on the minutes to obtain 1380.
2. Then convert the 1380 minutes to 23 hours.

This should ensure that minutes cannot be negative either.

Otherwise I think you’re fine.

PS Repeating myself from the comment: For production code use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for at time of day, and use its `plusMinutes` and `minusMinutes` methods for adding and subtracting minutes. Both of those methods accept positive and negative amounts of minutes.